# ¿Cómo generar PDF con laravel 5.4 dompdf data?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, pdf

Necesito generar un archivo .pdf con dompdf pero no me genera nada cuando presiono el boton.

Mi `PDFController`

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Product;

use PDF;


class PDFController extends Controller

{

public function pdf(Request $request){
    $products=Product::all();
    view()->share('products', $products);
    if ($request->has('descargar')) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('cart.index');
        return $pdf->download('cotizacion');
    }
    return view('cart.index');
}

}
```

Vista que deseo generar en PDF, al final llamo a la ruta en el ultimo boton, `index.blade.php`

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>qty</th>
            <th>size</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach(Cart::content() as $cartItem)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                <td width="50px">
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->rowId], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                    <input name="qty" type="text" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}">


                </td>
                <td>
                    <div > {!! Form::select('size', ['small'=>'Small','medium'=>'Medium','large'=>'Large'] , $cartItem->options->has('size')?$cartItem->options->size:'' ) !!}
                       </div>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input style="float: left"  type="submit" class="button success small" value="Ok">
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                    <form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}}"  method="POST">
                       {{csrf_field()}}
                       {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                       <input class="button small alert" type="submit" value="Delete">
                     </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                Tax: ${{Cart::tax()}} <br>
                Sub Total: $ {{Cart::subtotal()}} <br>
                Grand Total: $ {{Cart::total()}}
            </td>
            <td>Items: {{Cart::count()}}

            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{route('checkout.shipping')}}" class="button">Checkout</a>
    <a href="{{route('pdf')}}" class="button small alert">Import to PDF</a>
</div>



@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Cart Items</h3>


        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>qty</th>
                <th>size</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach(Cart::content() as $cartItem)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                    <td width="50px">
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->rowId], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                        <input name="qty" type="text" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}">


                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div > {!! Form::select('size', ['small'=>'Small','medium'=>'Medium','large'=>'Large'] , $cartItem->options->has('size')?$cartItem->options->size:'' ) !!}
                           </div>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input style="float: left"  type="submit" class="button success small" value="Ok">
                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                        <form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}}"  method="POST">
                           {{csrf_field()}}
                           {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                           <input class="button small alert" type="submit" value="Delete">
                         </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Tax: ${{Cart::tax()}} <br>
                    Sub Total: $ {{Cart::subtotal()}} <br>
                    Grand Total: $ {{Cart::total()}}
                </td>
                <td>Items: {{Cart::count()}}

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <a href="{{route('checkout.shipping')}}" class="button">Checkout</a>
        <a href="{{route('pdf')}}" class="button small alert">Import to PDF</a>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Mi ruta, `web.php`

```
Route::get('/pdf', 'PDFController@pdf')->name('pdf');
```

Comment: ¿donde mandas la request con una variable llamada "descargar"?

Answer (score 0):

Este problema lo tenia yo, Pero no es seguro que sea tu caso.

Resulta y pasa que esta librería necesita unos [módulos](http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php) de PHP específicos. Por lo que una instancia de Apache con PHP por defecto no los trae, Tienes que instalarlo o habilitarlo.

Por esta razón no aparece en tu `Localhost`.

La solución que yo encontré para mi problema (recuerda que puede que no sea tu caso), fue instalar dichos módulos. O en mi caso como poseía un hosting compartido, en cpanel habilite el modulo de dom

[image: Habilitación de dom]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Con respecto a la instalación del DOM en tu local, no me instalo, o no lo instale bien. Por eso no te documento sobre estos pasos.

Espero te ayude y nos cuentas como te fue.

> PD: si pudiste instalar el DOM en tu localhost, compartenos los pasos a pasos que hiciste para que otro pueda hacerlo.